# node express + formidable + form with multipart/form-data how to get req.body?

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I'm using [mean stack](http://mean.io/)

and [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to upload file

the form has a multipart/form-data attribute

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

but the rq.body is empty.
How can I get it ?

Comment: Did you include the bodyParser middleware

Comment: No because of http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html therefore I do the upload with formidable

Comment: Then you'd have to follow the documentation for the plugin, seems like there is a `form.parse` method etc. Without the middleware that creates the `req.body`, it won't be there. Personally I use the bodyParser in production and have never seen anyone try to exploit the "file spam" issue.

Comment: the signature is form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) so ... there is no handle :(

Comment: I got it console.log(fields.title); thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using formidable for multipart upload, you can get req.body fields in

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files)
```

fields.item