# data in form isn't showing in req.body

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using the mean.js framework so I know I have bodyParser show below

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
```

I'm also using formidable to send images to the server

but when I use a form below

HTML

```
  <form action="/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
      <input type="text" name="title"><br>
      <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
```

and I console.log(req.body) I get an empty object instead of an object with the key "title" and its value

```
exports.upload = function(req, res) {


      console.log(req.body) // prints an empty object
}
```

I don't know why I'm not getting any data in the body

Comment: I think it odd to say using the `mean.js` framework -- more applicable to say you're using `ExpressJS`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Got it... I found a similar question:

[node express + formidable + form with multipart/form-data how to get req.body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238334/node-express-formidable-form-with-multipart-form-data-how-to-get-req-body?rq=1)

Credit goes to Whisher, thanks a lot

In the comments section, Whisher states that you get the data in the fields parameter.